# Lookup channel by name

Tags: slack-api

Is there an `API` to look up the `channel ID` by the channel name? What I basically need is to find the `IDs` of members in a channel and I only know the channel name. What would be the easiest way to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no single call API to do that.

You'll need a couple of API calls to do that.
Firstly, you need to get the list of channels available in the workspace.

 https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list

Then, match the channel name & get the Channel Id.

Using this channel Id, you can get list of members:

 https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.members

Ideally, you should **use channel Id instead of channel Name**

 But if your use case does not allow that, you can use the given solution.

Comment: which is horrible if you think about it, my slack has 8k channels and I know only a channel name as an input. So I want to ensure it exists and users that I also have as an input are invited. So I must list 8k slack channel to determine if one of them exists. Ew.

Comment: @kek_mek, may be you can iterate from user's perspective. See what all conversations (channels) user is part of?